# Notepad ++ Find String and place symbol at beginning of line

Tags: notepad++

I have 5000 lines. I need to find if a line contains a certain word phrase such as "package" and put a "1%" at the beginning of it. How would I do this with replace in notepad++?

An example being:

DOGS AND CATS

if the line contains the word "DOGS" anywhere in the string make the new line:

1% DOGS AND CATS

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1677641/edit) and add sample text and expected result as well as your attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: What does "1%" stand for?

Comment: I am using % as a delimiter to import the text to excel

Comment: Please don't answer in comments, but edit your question adding relevant info. That way it's available for community members without the need of digging it out from comment threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?=.*DOGS)`
- Replace with: `%1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
(?=.*DOGS)      # positive lookahead, make sure we have DOGS somewhere in the line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: A follow up question. If the line does not start with %1 add a % at the beginning. for example: %1DOGS AND CATS, (next line) %CATS AND BIRDS stemming off your example above

Comment: @TariqAl-Attrash: It's possible to do but it I can't reply in comment because it is a bit complex. You should ask a new question with all details. But if my answer works for for you for the actual question, feel free to mark it accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I did some trial and error and got it to work, ^(?! 1 %) worked for me